# How to assign rank with single query to multiple colums ? 

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, rank

Lets say i have int price column in table_1 and i have int priceRank column table_1 again. Now is that possible with single query to order by price desc and assign them their rank via row_number. So the biggest price would get rank 1 and second biggest would get rank 2 and goes on. priceRank column will be updated here via the order of rows returned. How can i do that  ? is that possible ? thank you.

I'm  using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
;with C as
(
  select priceRank,
         row_number() over(order by price desc) as rn
  from Table_1
)
update C
set priceRank = rn
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119397/

Use [`rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) if you want ties to have the same rank and use [`dense_rank`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) if you don't want any gaps in the rank values.